# ブログサイトの記事内の商品群を並べ替えできるソートボックスを設置したい

Tags: css

自サイトの記事内に配置した商品を値段順や商品発売日順などにする、フィルターボックスを作りたいと思っています。以下の画像はFANZAからスクリーンショットしたものですが、丁度こんな具合のソートのボックスを作りたいと思っているのです。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

このような動的な仕組みを作るには、どのような知識が必要とされるのでしょうか？
つまりは、CSSやPHP、JSなどを応用すれば実現できるのか。また、その場合においてどのようなコードを書けばいいのか等、私は経験が浅いために課題を前に進めることが出来ていません（サイト制作はWPを使っています）

フィルターボックスの作成経験がある方や、その問題に取り組んだ事がある方がいれば、どんな技術が必要になり、どのように仕組みを実現させたか、また出来なかったかを教えていただくとありがたいです。

自サイトの現在の商品陳列はこのようになっています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: フィルターボックスのないただの商品リストを出す仕組み作りはできる前提ですか？それとも商品リストすら作ることがかなわないですか？

Comment: ご返答ありがとうございます。現在商品の陳列の仕方は、追加した図の様になっている状態です。PC4カラム・スマホ2カラムで、アマゾンの商品リンクなど画像に埋め込んで貼り付けてあります。

Comment: フィルタリングしたい商品の属性(値段や発売日)はデータベース等によって構造化や正規化は行われていますか？

Comment: 恥ずかしながら、そのへんの知識がまったく追いついていないのが実情です。そのあたりの知識はどの本や、ブログサイトを読めば分かるようになるでしょうか？

Comment: 質問が変わってしまっています。「どういう技術か知りたい」なのか、「どういう本やサイトで勉強したらいいのか」なのかはっきりさせましょう。また後者はリスト質問にあたる可能性があるので注意は必要そうですが、、

Answer (score 1):

まず「フィルターボックス」や「ソートボックス」という表現は一般的ではありません。
(Google 等で検索しても物理的な "箱" が出てくるだけです)

---

単にパーツとしてのフィルタ (プルダウンメニュー) 項目を表示させるだけなら HTML だけでも実現可能ですが、実際に商品を任意のソート順に表示するには **PHP** やデータベース接続の知識が必要になってくると思います。

コメント欄でも指摘がある通り、あらかじめデータベース等にソートをかけたいデータが揃っていれば、どのプログラミング言語でもソート自体は比較的簡単に実現可能なはずです。

Comment: 1. HTMLやCSSでフィルタメニューを表示する。
2. 商品データをソートできる仕組みをPHPでつくる。
3. 閲覧者が1.で作ったフィルタメニューからソートする事ができる仕組みをつくる
という設計イメージになるのでしょうか？